Show four buttons horizontally in same row but switch to two rows when font size is increased
Using XML Android, I need to achieve a layout where four buttons are placed in a single row with equal weight for all four buttons but when I increase the font size I need to show them in 2*2 (the last two buttons show go to second row), Can some one help?
I tried using FlexboxLayout but it does not limit the rows to two, it shows them in three rows at maximum font.
thanks in advance

Assuming u have created the Logic of fontsize change Dynamically
U can simply use gridlayout and change it's columncount value when font size changed
Exemple:
Let's said that Ur font size is changing by clicking a button
simply use setonclicklistener and give Ur condition
if size<=5{
    your_gridlayout.columnCount=4
}else{
    your_gridlayout.columnCount=2
}

your idea is not clear enough but this is how i get it if i'm wrong ,be more specific please...
